# ansible if else statement to run only required task

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am working on playbook which should run with conditions

For example when choice = repos I want to run first task and if choice = projects I want to run second task

```
tasks:
  - name: Run python script for generating Empty Repos Report
    command: python GetRepos.py -o {{ org }} -p {{ pat }}
    register: result
  - debug: msg="{{result.stdout}}"
    when:
       - "{{ choice }}" == "Repos"

  - name: Run python script for generating Empty Repos Report
    command: python GetRepos.py -o {{ org }} -p {{ pat }}
    register: result
  - debug: msg="{{result.stdout}}"
    when:
      - "{{ choice }}" == "Projects"
```

This gives me error because of wrong syntax , what's the right syntax to achieve this ?

Comment: As an example of the problem, simple `- debug: msg=OK` would be enough. See [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax

```yaml
tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: Run first task
    when: choice == "Repos"

  - debug:
      msg: Run second task
    when: choice == "Projects"
```

Optionally, use the default value to avoid crashing due to the undefined variable *choice*. For example

```yaml
    when: choice|default("Undefined") == "Projects"
```